# Objective C - Structuring classes logic

Tags: objective-c, architecture, singleton, logic, structure

I'm relatively new to Objective C coding, so please help me with this :

In my code, I have a class named GameData, which is a singleton, and it contains some methods, and it's this class which manage the scoring system. My question is, should I create another class for the Scores that I would store in GameData, or should I keep it this way? I want to be sure because I have a lot of methods for the score management! THANKS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you find that you are creating a lot of methods in object A to deal with a specific value or specific set of values contained in A, the value or values should be composed into class B with all B-value associated methods.

Seeing as you're noticing this issue yourself, you should probably move the values and methods associated with `Score` data into a separate object.

For the methods that you move, ask yourself if the method is something that a `Score` should know about, or something that the `GameData` manager should know about.

For example, a `Score` probably shouldn't know about the existence of other scores because it's `GameData`'s responsibility to manage the composition of those scores. Conversely, the `GameData` manager shouldn't manually sort your scores based off of some internal `Score` metric (such as `pointsGained` or `secondsToFinish`), but instead rely on `Score` to implement a comparison method to other objects that makes sense to `Score`. By giving objects only the information that matters to them in this example, you can make it easy to change how a `Score` ranks to other scores without needing to modify the `GameData` class.

Answer (score 1):

[Separating responsibilities (pdf)](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByOwmqah_nuGNHEtcU5OekdDMkk/edit?pli=1) is a good software design principle. Depending on your needs, and on the change vectors you foresee in your code, moving the code to a dedicated score keeping class should help.

Also, be sure to check other important object-oriented design principles, like the [SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod).